# How to put video on Website

Tags: html

I am new to working with videos and what i'm trying to accomplish is putting a video on my site. I have been researching and havent found to much, any help would be very much appreciated. Here is what I have so far.

```
  <embed "images/K36U21TR.wmv" width="300" height="300" />
```

Comment: I dont see any reference to VB.Net, though you tagged it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My preffered method is to upload the video to YouTube and place it on your site using their embed code which is an iframe tag.

This provides the benefit of your users using YouTube's bandwidth when they are watching the video rather than yours.

Alternatively you could look at using the HTML5 VIDEO tag.

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_video.asp

Comment: Thank you for your response, and reasoning of one method over the other

Answer (score 0):

```
<video width="300" height="300" controls>
    <source src="images/K36U21TR.wmv" type="video/wmv">
</video>
```

Answer (score 0):

video tag : (Supprot : IE, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari)

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls="controls">
  <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="movie.ogg" type="video/ogg">
  <source src="movie.webm" type="video/webm">
</video>
```

embed tag : (Supprot : IE, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari)

```
<embed src="helloworld.swf">
```